# Open source project for mobile testing practice

Tags: manual-testing, android, mobile, open-source

I am a software tester. I want to practice software testing on mobile/smartphone(preferably on android OS). Are there any open source software projects or applications which i can test on my mobile? I mean to say is there any open source projects for android platform that on which i can practice mobile testing/mobile app testing(mainly manual testing)?

Comment: Try SeeTestManual, it is not free of charge but you can get a free trial.

Comment: Do you want a web app or native app?

Comment: IIUC, you want to volunteer to do testing for some/any open source Android app?

Comment: @chris: Anyone- Webapp or native app.

Comment: @Peter: ya as a volunteer in an open source project as software tester.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are :)

[This is a collection of Android Apps which are open source and you can test them](https://github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Open Source Android app to test. You can use just about any .apk built for Release [[Source]](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Instrumenting+Android+Applications). This is unlike iOS apps that have to be built using a Debug build and have the test framework packaged in [[Source]](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/Instrumenting+iOS+Applications).

Tools like Xamarin (free with Visual Studio Community for Windows and Xamarin Studio for OSX) or SeeTest (paid app) only ask for the apk file and runs with it.

I use Xamarin but linked SeeTest as my sources since the docs were easier to find.